# Saving an object with its related objects using WCF Data Services

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf-data-services

I'm using WCF Data Services which is working well for most things, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to update an entity that has a related entity collection.  For example, in the code below I have a Batch object which has related Departments.  In my database this is represented as three tables - Batches, Departments, and Batches_Departments.  EF exposes this to me as Batch object with navigation property for Departments.

In the code listed below the Batch object is created and the Departments collection is populated, but when I call SaveChanges, only the Batch object is created in the database.  The Departments are ignored.  If I set a breakpoint on the SaveChanges line, I can verify the Departments collection is populated.

```
private void Save()
{
  var batch = new DataService.Batch() { Description = txtDescription.Text, Filename = txtFilename.Text };

  foreach (var department in lstDepartments.CheckedItems)
  {
    var dept = _ctx.Departments
      .Select(d => d)
      .Where(d => d.DepartmentID == ((DataService.Department)department).DepartmentID)
      .First();

    batch.Departments.Add(dept);
  }

  _ctx.AddToBatches(batch);
  _ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but I can't seem to find it.  Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a limitation in the current generated code. You will also need to add the following line of code to your program:

```
context.AddLink(batch, "Departments", dept);
```

You could also hook into the PropertyChanged event for batch if you prefer.

Edit: I found another option as well. You can do the following rather than `AddLink`:

```
private void Save()
{
  var batches = new DataServiceCollection<Batch>(_ctx);
  var batch = new DataService.Batch() { Description = txtDescription.Text, Filename = txtFilename.Text };
  batches.Add(batch);

  foreach (var department in lstDepartments.CheckedItems)
  {
    var dept = _ctx.Departments
      .Select(d => d)
      .Where(d => d.DepartmentID == ((DataService.Department)department).DepartmentID)
      .First();

    batch.Departments.Add(dept);
  }

  // _ctx.AddToBatches(batch);
  _ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I tried this earlier but got a message that said "The context is not currently tracking the entity."  Since your post confirmed that this approach was correct, I dug in a little and found that I needed to move the _ctx.AddToBatchs(batch) line up before the foreach. (I assumed earlier that it was the dept object that wasn't being tracked.) After doing this and adding the AddLink line within the body of the foreach, it worked as I would have expected.  Thanks again.